# Exception: Error in simplesamlphp_auth.module: no valid unique id attribute set

Tags: drupal-7, simplesamlphp, simple-authentication

I installed simplesamlphp and simplesamlauth. When I try to login I'm getting this error can anyone help me to solve this?

Exception:

> Error in simplesamlphp_auth.module: no valid unique id
>   attribute set. in _simplesamlphp_auth_get_authname() (line 419 of
>   /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/simplesamlphp_auth/simplesamlphp_auth.module).

Answer (score 1):

It's occurring because the IdP is not providing the attribute that you've specified in the "Which attribute from simpleSAMLphp should be used as unique identifier for the user" field on the module's config page. If (for example) you are trying to test the module using the IdP at TestShib.org, you will get that error because neither the default name in that field, nor the other name that's suggested, match any of the attributes provided by TestShib.org. So, assuming that you have no control over the IdP, you need to figure out which, among the attributes that *are* being provided, will work as a unique identifier and enter that name in that field. Again using TestShib.org as an example, if you log in using the simpleSAMLphp application (not the module), you will see a list of the provided attributes on that page, with their names in the left column.